# C++ XOR encryption

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography

After reading several white papers on cryptography and runtime PE crypters, I decided to write my own. It's very simple and only for educational purposes.

Here is the GitHub repo: https://github.com/Jyang772/XOR_Crypter

I have two questions.

- **First**, why do I have to keep changing my file permissions to start
  every outputted .exe (File created by Builder.exe not the compiler)? It creates a file that is `Shared`. I have to right click it and select share with `Nobody`. Does this have something to do with the File Access and Security Rights? I am using `CreateFile()` and `Readfile` to read and write the input and output files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx

[image]

- **Second**, I can't seem to get XOR encryption to work. It seems pretty
  straight forward for what I have done. The byte sizes are the same. While I was investigating, I had the Builder and the Stub each output a file with the file data unencrypted. They are the same. Then I tried with the data encrypted. There is no doubt the data is encrypted with the cipher, however it shows up blank when it is decrypted by the stub later on. I'm confused.

Here is my XOR implementation:

fs = byte size
Rsize = byte size
Should be the same.

Builder:

```
 char cipher[] ="penguin";
      for (int i = 0; i < fs; i++)
        {   
                FB[i] ^= cipher[i % strlen(cipher)]; // Simple Xor chiper
        }
```

Stub:

```
char cipher[] = "penguin";
for (int i = 0; i < Rsize; i++)
    {
        RData[i] ^= cipher[i % strlen(cipher)];
    }
```

If I were to comment out the encryption function in the Builder and Stub, the crypted file runs fine. Uhh, except with the permissions error.

I'm also trying to include a options menu where the user can select the encryption method used. Perhaps I might have done something wrong there? The Builder.exe adds one byte containing the user's choice to the end of `FB` buffer. Stub.exe reads that and determines which encryption method is used to decrypt the data.

Comment: Are you remembering to open your files as `binary`?

Comment: @JoeZ I thought CreateFile() and ReadFile() always opens files in binary mode.

Comment: File permissions havenothing to do with encryption, or programming.

Comment: @EJP It's the file outputted by my Builder.exe. Not the compiler. The compiler builds Builder.exe and Stub.exe fine. I'm not sure why the file outputted is always `Shared`. I have to right click it and select share with `Nobody` in order to run the file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off, with XOR "encryption", your "encrypt" and "decrypt" functions should be the same:

```
void xor_crypt(const char *key, int key_len, char *data, int data_len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data_len; i++)
        data[i] ^= key[ i % key_len ];
}
```

You should be able to use this same function in both the "XOR Crypter" program as well as your "Stub" program.

It's not a very C++ style; ordinarily you'd use `std::string` or `std::vector`.  For example:

```
void xor_crypt(const std::string &key, std::vector<char>& data)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i != data.size(); i++)
        data[i] ^= key[ i % key.size() ];
}
```

Then in the program that calls this, you'd declare:

```
std::string key = "penguin";
```

and you'd read your file in like so:

```
std::vector<char> file_data;  // With your current program, make this a global.

fs = GetFileSize(efile, NULL);
file_data.resize(fs);    // set vector length equal to file size

// Note:  Replace &( file_data[0] ) with file_data.data() if you have C++11 support
ReadFile(efile, (LPVOID)( &( file_data[0] )), fs, &bt, NULL);   

if (fs != bt)
    // error reading file:  report it here.
```

Then you would simply encrypt with `xor_crypt( key, file_data );`.  To write the XOR-crypted data to your resource, I believe you'd call your existing function with:

```
// replace &( file_data[0] ) with file_data.data() if C++11
WriteToResources(output, 1, (BYTE *)&( file_data[0] ), file_data.size() );
```

I suspect the real issue is with the Windows APIs you're using.  Does `LoadResource` give you mutable data, or are you required to copy it?  I don't know the Windows API, but I wouldn't be surprised if `LoadResource` gives you a read-only copy.

If you do need to make your own copy in order to modify the resource, then in your "Stub" program recovering the XOR-crypted resource should look something like this:

```
std::vector<char> RData;

void Resource(int id)
{
    size_t Rsize;

    HRSRC hResource = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(1), RT_RCDATA);
    HGLOBAL temp = LoadResource(NULL, hResource);
    Rsize = SizeofResource(NULL, hResource);
    RData.resize(RSize);
    memcpy( (void*)&(RData[0]), temp, RSize );  // replace &RData[0] with RData.data() if C++11
}
```

and the decryption in your "Stub" should just be `xor_crypt( key, RData );`.

I have one last thought.  The biggest bug I see in your "Stub" program is this line:

```
    switch (RData[strlen(RData)-1])
```

Once you've XOR-crypted your data, some of the bytes will become zero.  The `strlen()` function will not return the index of the last byte in your `RData` as a result.  And, there's a different, more subtle error:  This returns the last byte of the string, not the last byte of the resource.  I can't really see how this line was ever correct; rather, I suspect your program was working when encryption was disabled in spite of itself, by falling through to the `default` of the switch-case.

If you really intend to distinguish between different types of data based on the last byte of the resource payload, then you really should just use the size returned by the Windows API to find that byte.

If you switch to using `vector<char>` as I suggest above, then you can find that with `RData.back()`.  Otherwise, if you continue using `char *`, then that byte would be `RData[RSize - 1]`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read through my code and giving me a very detailed answer. I have taken your advice and commented out my C-style functions with the ones you suggested. 

The only part that I needed to fix was making sure `file_data` and `data` in the xor function were the same. Otherwise I'm just XOR crypting a copy of `file_data`

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I included your name in my project. 

The only problem I have to fix now is figuring out why the crypted file is always being outputted as a shared file.

Comment: Here is a slight variation that uses a 64-bit integer as a key.

    `_UINT8 *XorCipher(_UINT8 *arr, size_t arrLen, _UINT64 key)
    {
     // Allocate Output buffer
     _UINT8 *outArr = new _UINT8[arrLen]; 
     
     // Refer to the 64-bit key as a 8 byte byte array
     _UINT8 *keyArr = (_UINT8*)&key;
    
     for (size_t i = 0; i < arrLen; i++)
      outArr[i] = arr[i] ^ keyArr[i % 8];
    
     return outArr;
    }`

Comment: One thing to watch out for with that approach, @IngeHenriksen, is endianness.  In this case, the same type of computer will be used to encrypt and decrypt.  If two different machines are sharing information, then they both have to understand the endianness of the key.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your content data, you write char option in allocated memory pointed by FB or after it ([buffer overrun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)) in "C++ Builder/main.cpp" when calling strcat(FB, choice).

Fix: allocate enough space in FB for data + option char. As you are dealing with binary data you should not use string functions (ex: [strcat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759925%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

```
FB = new char[fs + 1];
memcpy(FB +fs, option, 1); // copy the option at end
```

Comment: I have a question. Why would I only allocate 5 spaces for FB?

Comment: Update, should be size of data not 4 ... my mistake

Comment: Hmm, not sure why it's not working.
I decided to remove the choices menu. Must be something with the encryption.

Comment: Use `std::vector`, not `new`. This isn’t C.