# A way around my XOR Encryption requiring plaintext size

Tags: php, c++, encryption, xor

I looked at some of the XOR examples and am unable to find an answer.

This is the code I'm using for PHP:

```
 for($i=0;$i<strlen($text);)
 {
     for($j=0;($j<strlen($key) && $i<strlen($text));$j++,$i++)
     {
         $outText .= $text{$i} ^ $key{$j};
         //echo 'i='.$i.', '.'j='.$j.', '.$outText{$i}.'<br />'; //for debugging
     }
 }
```

And the resulting code for decryption in C++:

```
for (int i = 0; i < original.size();)
{
    for (int j = 0; (j < key.size() && i < original.size()); j++, i++)
    {
        decrypted += encrypted[i] ^ key[j];
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble getting around the need for the plaintext's size (std::string original in this case).

Without, hopefully, drastically changing the way I do the algorithm, is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since the XOR encryption is done on octect/byte-boundaries, len(input) = len(output) - or something is wrong.

Comment: Plain old C++ will do exactly as you told it, but I expect PHP might think it knows better what you meant. If really `len(input) != len(output)` then I would expect that PHP is doing some charset conversions (single-byte to some unicode perhaps?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ciphertext and plaintext are the same length.  So either size will do.

You also do not need two levels of loop nest to do this in PHP or C++.

Your code should look more like this:

```
 $textlen = strlen($text);
 $keylen  = strlen($key);
 for ($i = 0; $i < $textlen; $i++)
 {
     $outText .= chr( ord( $text{$i} ) ^ ord ( $key{$i % $keylen} ) );
 }
```

I answered another question on XOR encryption [here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365005/c-xor-encryption/20472972#20472972) since it seems to be all the rage these days.

BTW, if you try to backport this PHP code back to C++, be aware that (unlike PHP), `strlen` stops at ASCII NULs, and won't do what you want.  You're better off using either `std::string` or `vector<char>` for the C++ version.  (See link above for my C++ code.)

Comment: Not quite sure how I didn't notice that, well I now at least have a better understanding of it!  Thanks for the reply!